# How can you swap two fixed-size opencl-c arrays

Tags: arrays, opencl, swap

I want to swap two arrays within an opencl-c call in that manner:

```
uint tmp_a[L] = {...};
uint tmp_b[L] = {...};
swap(tmp_a, tmp_b); // (tmp_a, tmp_b) <- (tmp_b, tmp_a)
```

I would like to do it just by swapping the base addresses of the two pointers, but unfortunatley

```
void swap(uint num_a[L], uint num_b[L]) {
    uint* tmp = num_a;
    num_a = num_b;
    num_b = tmp;
}
```

doesn't work.

In reality I do it now this way:

```
for(int i = 0; i < L; ++i) {
        const uint tmp = num_a[i];
        num_a[i] = num_b[i];
        num_b[i] = tmp;
}
```

I would like to reduce this unnecessary work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An array is just a pointer to a chunk of memory. When you pass an array to a function (as in your code snippet), you are passing the *value* of that pointer to the function. Passing an argument to a function is much like an assignment operation. Consider this simple example:

```
void foo(uint arg[L])
{
  arg = NULL;
}

uint bar[L] = {...};
foo(bar);
```

This is essentially the same as:

```
uint bar[L] = {...};
uint arg[L] = bar;
arg = NULL;
```

The pointer stored in `bar` hasn't been affected by the assignment that happened inside the `foo` function. If we *did* want to modify the pointer stored in `bar` inside the `foo` function, we should instead pass the *address* of `bar`:

```
void foo(uint *arg[L])
{
  *arg = NULL;
}

uint bar[L] = {...};
foo(&bar);
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
uint data[L] = {...};
uint *arg[L] = &bar;
*arg = NULL;
```

This time, `arg` points to the memory that stores the data contained in `bar`, which is the pointer to the array values. This means that if we modify the stuff that `arg` points to, then we will also be modifying `bar`.

---

Applying this to your code snippet would look like this:

```
void swap(uint *num_a[L], uint *num_b[L])
{
  uint *tmp = *num_a;
  *num_a = *num_b;
  *num_b = tmp;
}

...

uint tmp_a[L] = {...};
uint tmp_b[L] = {...};
swap(&tmp_a, &tmp_b); // (tmp_a, tmp_b) <- (tmp_b, tmp_a)
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked!

Anyway: Do you have an explanation why the old version didn't work?

Comment: @user2292040 I've added an explanation, hope that helps.

Comment: Than you for your further explanation!